# Understanding The Logic Behind A jQuery Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I couldn't find any such question in StackOverFlow (please forgive me if I missed any!).

The code below is messing me up. Please note that this is to resume/pause animation.

```
$(function() {
    $('.slider').css("animation-play-state", "running");
    var animVar = $('.slider').css("animation-play-state"); //animVar === "running" and on next click, it gets updated to "paused"
    $('.slider').click(function() {
            $(this).css("animation-play-state", function() {
                if (animVar === "running") {
                    return "paused"; //returns "paused" to the function and the css property gets updated, overriding the one at the first line, changing the animVar on the next line.
                    } else {
                    return "running"; //returns "running" to the function and the css property gets updated, overriding the one at the first line, changing the animVar on the next line.
                }   
            }); 
    }); 
});
```

The thing is, if I don't update the animVar inside the if/else statements, the code is not working. What's happening instead is, once I click on it, it pauses and on successive clicks, it doesn't resume.

But if I do update animVar inside the if/else statements like `animVar = "running"/"paused"`, it works fine.

My question is, at first I am setting the animation play state to 'running'.

That sets animVar to 'running'.

The if condition is met and the animation is 'paused' as expected.

But this should also override the `$('.slider').css("animation-play-state", "running");` at the top and reset the animVar to 'paused', so that on next click, the if condition is not met and the else statement is carried out, thus toggling the play state between running and paused on clicks.

Apparently, my logic is going wrong somewhere. Can someone please make me understand? I mean, the inside function is a closure, so it should be able to access and update the variables of the outer function, right?

Here's another thing. If on each click, the browser is reading it from the top and thus, resetting the play state to "running" each time, how would the updating of animVar inside if/else work? It's getting overridden each time the browser reads the whole function afresh.

Please help me.

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Nobody is going to re-type your code just to evaluate it. You need to post actual code, not pictures of code. If you want us to know something about the code that's what comments are for, not scribbles of red hand written text on a picture of code.

Comment: Don't post screenshot as code - Post the code **in the question** please [edit] and add it

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that the code in the picture is not the code that's running. `animVar` gets run once and never updated. Saying `$(this).css(...)` would never update animVar, either. I have a feeling you have the `var animVar = ...` assignment statement inside your click handler, when it should be outside.

Comment: Sure, done as suggested :-)

Comment: @mhodges this is the code that I am running. Here's the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vudeboh). The question is, why would it not get updated as I changed the CSS property in the click()? What is the process that it is going in behind the scenes?

Comment: @SamC `var animVar = $('.slider').css("animation-play-state");` is a one-time assignment, not a live-link. I think that may be where you are getting confused. It is copying the *value* of the animation-play-state css property at that exact moment in time, and storing it in a variable called `animVar`. By nature of how primitive values are stored in JS, `animVar` will not ever get updated unless you explicitly say `animVar = ...`

Comment: @mhodges I think we are playing with the assigning with "value" vs. assigning with "reference" here, if I am making any sense at all. So, it does not get updated until I do it inside the function. Otherwise, it is always set to "running". Thanks so much.

Comment: @SamC That is correct =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you are trying to toggle between "running" and "paused" as value of the animation-play-state property?

See below.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".slider").click(function() {
    var sliderClass = $(".slider").css("animation-play-state");
    if(sliderClass == "running") {
      $('.slider').css("animation-play-state", "paused");
      console.log("running");
    } else {
      $(".slider").css("animation-play-state", "running");
      console.log("paused");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.slider {
animation-play-state: running; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider"> hallo </div>
```

Comment: Yes, I am. In my code, the animVar is not getting updated even when the CSS play state property is getting updated. That's the question.

Comment: Because you never change the value of the variable? You declare it once above the onClick event, after that I see no code that changes the variable. But what I am trying to say is that you do not need the variable in the first place.

Comment: Right got it, thanks. That's an elegant code BTW. Selecting it as an answer.